# Getting Land Use data from National Land Cover dataset

Tags: r, land-use, nlcd

I'm downloading data from the National Land Cover database using the get_nlcd tool from the FedData package. Here is an example for documentation for this package

```
library(FedData)

vepPolygon <- polygon_from_extent(raster::extent(672800,740000,4102000,4170000), 
                              proj4string='+proj=utm +datum=NAD83 +zone=12')

# Get the NLCD (USA ONLY)
# Returns a raster
Veg <- get_nlcd(template=vepPolygon, label='VEPIIN',force.redo=TRUE)

#Get Land Use Stats

LandUseStats<-as.data.frame(Veg@data@attributes)
LandUseStats<-LandUseStats[!LandUseStats$Count == 0,]

LandUseStats

  ID OID Value      Count Red Green Blue    NLCD.2011.Land.Cover.Class Opacity
1   0   0     0 7854240512   0     0    0                  Unclassified       1
12 11  11    11  469012527   0     0    0                    Open Water       1
13 12  12    12    1599206   0     0    0            Perennial Snow/Ice       1
22 21  21    21  292251633   0     0    0         Developed, Open Space       1
23 22  22    22  131633826   0     0    0      Developed, Low Intensity       1
24 23  23    23   59456652   0     0    0   Developed, Medium Intensity       1
25 24  24    24   21426522   0     0    0     Developed, High Intensity       1
32 31  31    31  110507264   0     0    0                   Barren Land       1
42 41  41    41  973617734   0     0    0              Deciduous Forest       1
43 42  42    42 1037912310   0     0    0              Evergreen Forest       1
44 43  43    43  179845520   0     0    0                  Mixed Forest       1
53 52  52    52 1940362409   0     0    0                   Shrub/Scrub       1
72 71  71    71 1306961628   0     0    0                   Herbaceuous       1
82 81  81    81  597234572   0     0    0                   Hay/Pasture       1
83 82  82    82 1392218141   0     0    0              Cultivated Crops       1
91 90  90    90  347144473   0     0    0                Woody Wetlands       1
96 95  95    95  116679631   0     0    0 Emergent Herbaceuous Wetlands       1

#Compare to plot
plot(Veg)
```

If I understand the "Count" to be the number of pixels represented in the associated plot, then when comparing the plot to the Stats, the two don't seem to match. Nor do I understand why close to half the data is "unclassified".

Is there a better way to extract the land use data used in the plot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the `@data@attributes` element is metadata about the data set as a whole, not the particular extract. I tried `get_nlcd` with a smaller polygon region and the table in `@data@attributes` was identical.

The actual pixel class counts in the data are:

```
> table(Veg[])

     11      21      22      23      24      31      41      42      43      52 
  24691   68988   22099    2810     272   35671  459772 1929928    3474 3129873 
     71      81      82      90      95 
 305054  306191  327458   41239     530
```

You can look these up in the data attributes, and it seems you need to add 1 to get the OID value:

```
> Veg@data@attributes[[1]][1+unique(Veg[]),]
   ID OID Value      Count Red Green Blue    NLCD.2011.Land.Cover.Class Opacity
43 42  42    42 1037912310   0     0    0              Evergreen Forest       1
53 52  52    52 1940362409   0     0    0                   Shrub/Scrub       1
83 82  82    82 1392218141   0     0    0              Cultivated Crops       1
82 81  81    81  597234572   0     0    0                   Hay/Pasture       1
22 21  21    21  292251633   0     0    0         Developed, Open Space       1
72 71  71    71 1306961628   0     0    0                   Herbaceuous       1
23 22  22    22  131633826   0     0    0      Developed, Low Intensity       1
91 90  90    90  347144473   0     0    0                Woody Wetlands       1
42 41  41    41  973617734   0     0    0              Deciduous Forest       1
32 31  31    31  110507264   0     0    0                   Barren Land       1
12 11  11    11  469012527   0     0    0                    Open Water       1
24 23  23    23   59456652   0     0    0   Developed, Medium Intensity       1
44 43  43    43  179845520   0     0    0                  Mixed Forest       1
25 24  24    24   21426522   0     0    0     Developed, High Intensity       1
96 95  95    95  116679631   0     0    0 Emergent Herbaceuous Wetlands       1
```

Most of those columns, including the Count, seem a bit useless.